# Evenly space icons whether they have notification badge or not

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

There won't be as many as shown in the image below, but this shows it more obviously.  I am looking to have a couple of font awesome icons that are overlaid with a bootstrap badge to indicate notifications.  The two problems I am having are:

1. When each of the icons have a notification badge, there is too much spacing between them
2. When an icon does not have a notification badge, they are no longer evenly spaced as a set of icons.

[image: Spacing Icons]

The html:

```
<div class="navbar-nav flex-row ml-md-auto d-none d-md-flex">
    <div class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener" aria-label="GitHub">
            <i class="fa fa-lg fa-bell"></i>
            <span class="notification-badge badge badge-danger">1</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener" aria-label="GitHub">
            <i class="fa fa-lg fa-calendar-alt"></i>
            <span class="notification-badge badge badge-danger">4</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
           aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="fas fa-lg fa-list-alt notification-icon"></i>
            {{--<span class="notification-badge badge badge-danger">2</span>--}}
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener" aria-label="GitHub">
            <i class="fa fa-lg fa-comment"></i>
            {{--<span class="notification-badge badge badge-danger">1</span>--}}
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
           aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="fas fa-lg fa-envelope notification-icon"></i>
            <span class="notification-badge badge badge-danger">2</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
span.notification-badge {
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
  right: 10px;
  border: $white 1px solid;
}
```

The rest is out-of-the-box Bootstrap 4.

Comment: Specify the width of each icon area with CSS. If the icon image is 48px wide, make the alloted area (e.g. a flexbox item) 64px wide. That way, the width is fixed with or without a badge.

Answer (score 0):

Try a negative right margin that is the width of the badge, something like:

```
span.notification-badge {
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
    right: 10px;
    border: $white 1px solid;
    margin-right: -18px;
}
```

Play around with the margin-right and the `.nav-item` or `.nav-link` margins to get to where you wanna be.